# What is the purpose of using the Boost.MPI library?

Tags: c++, boost, mpi, mpich

What is the purpose of using the Boost.MPI library? Does it increase performance? And what is the difference between it and the MPICH library?

Comment: Increase the performance of what?

Comment: For example communication or memory

Comment: @ehsan: It would really be cool if some library could increase the performance of my memory...

Comment: @PlasmaHH The library can not increase the performance of memory, but it may be can help you to use the entire of potential of system that you have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Boost.MPI [provides](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/mpi.html)

> an alternative C++ interface to MPI that better supports modern C++ development styles, including complete support for user-defined data types and C++ Standard Library types, arbitrary function objects for collective algorithms, and the use of modern C++ library techniques.

It intends

> to maintain maximal efficiency

but not to actually *improve* the performance of MPI; it can't, because it's still tied to existing MPI implementations (though it may implement some high-level patterns in a more efficient way than you would write them, depending on how much of an MPI expert you are). It's mainly more convenient than the regular C API.

Answer (score 7):

It is basically a "modern" c++ interface to the same old C API that is implemented in, say MPICH. Since it is using the same functions it cannot lead to any performance improvement but might help with the actual implementation by making it easier.

Comment: What performance? Its just a different interface to the same C API

Comment: Don't call C old :) It is a mature, solid language. Python is old.. C is not.

Comment: Python is old but C is not? Excuse me?

Answer (score 4):

The C++ bindings in MPI deprecated since version 2.2: http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi22-report/node328.htm

Boost.MPI based on C MPI API, so it is good decision for those who want C++ API: https://github.com/mpi-forum/mpi-forum-historic/issues/150

Comment: ... if they're happy with the subset of MPI functionality that Boost.MPI actually supports. See http://lists.mpi-forum.org/mpi-forum/2011/12/1396.php and http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html#mpi.c_mapping

Comment: The link above is broken but that post (which I discovered in the course of finding it that I wrote) can be found here: https://lists.mpi-forum.org/pipermail/mpi-forum/2011-December/001396.html